# Django - I want to display current rate depending on the category i select

Tags: django, ajax

here is my front-end and everything is working fine however, i don't want all rate to display at once, i want the rate to display one at a time depending on the card category i select.
From the image i uploaded, current rate of other card category are showing which i don't want, please i need help even if it will require using javascript of ajax

[image: here is my front-end and everything is working fine however, i don't want all rate at once, i want want the rate to display one at a time depending on the card category i select]

Here is my index(template)

```
{% for giftcard in giftcards %}
          <!-- Card -->
          <div class="col-lg-4 gift__card col-6 p-0">
            <a type="button" class="btn">
              <img class="img-fluid gift__card-img" src="{{ giftcard.card_image.url }}">
            </a>

            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-center">
              <div class="gift__card-modal-container py-5">
                <div class="card__container">
                  <div class="gift__card-overlay"></div>
                  <div class="container-fluid bg-light  gift__card-modal shadow-lg">
                    <div class="pop p-5">
                      <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 p-0 m-0">
                          <img class="img-fluid gift__card-img" style="width: 40rem;" src="{{ giftcard.card_image.url }}">
                          <p class="text-muted">Select the card category and the amount.</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 card-details">
                          <form class="card-form">
                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="card-category">Card category</label>
                            
                              <select id="category" class="form-select py-2" aria-label="Default select example">
                                {% for spec in giftcard.category_set.all %}
                                <option value="{{ spec.category }}">{{ spec.category }}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                              </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group py-2">
                              <label for="Amount">Amount</label>
                              <div class="d-flex align-items-center amount">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount"
                                  placeholder="Please enter amount">
                                <span class="">#100,000</span>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group py-3">
                              {% for spec in giftcard.category_set.all %}
                              <label for="rate">Current rate - {{ spec.rate }}</label>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </div>

                            <div class="border-none pt-2 pl-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                              <button type="button" class="btn  process-card-btn">Proceed</button>
                            </div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                


                <div class="gift__terms-card hide fade" id="terms" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                  aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content terms">
                      <div class="p-5">
                        <h4 class="terms-title pb-4">Trading terms</h4>
                        {% for spec in giftcard.category_set.all %}
                        <p class="pb-2">{{ spec.terms }}</p>
                        {% endfor %}

                        <div class="border-none pt-3 pl-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                          <button type="button" class="btn process-card-btn">Proceed</button>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          {% endfor %}
```

Here is my models

```
class Giftcard(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
card_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Giftcard/', blank=False)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    terms = models.TextField()
    card_category = models.ForeignKey(Giftcard, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is my views

```
def giftcard(request):
giftcards = Giftcard.objects.filter(publish=True)

context = {
    'giftcards': giftcards
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/giftcard.html', context)
```

Comment: You should consider some javascript that displays the rate depending on the selected card, and changes this when a different card is selected

Comment: i don't know how to write JavaScript's

Comment: When you want to get into webdevelopment, it is quite a mandatory skill. Perhaps consider using a framework like JQuery to have a good abstraction layer over the raw javascript.